# I want to change language of datatable dynamically without reloading the page ,

Tags: angular, datatable, smartadmin

```
onLangChange(langObj) {
}
```

The functions I want to reinitialize data table with new language JSON object without loading the page.
is possible to re-render the data table without losing filler and search attributes

Answer (score 0):

Angular is using the MVVM-Pattern to reactivate views without loading them again. They just rerendering the already shown items.

```
oldLangObj : Obj;

onLangChange(langObj) : void {
    this.oldLangObj = langObj;
}
```

Thats all. The MVVM-Pattern is doing the rest. As long as your `oldLangObj` is bind to the table. And of course, this should be in the .TS-file next to your .HTML-File for your table.

For more information check out this [link](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)